# Work to induce charge on grounded conductors

Tags: electromagnetism, conductors, method-of-images

I'm currently studying Method of Images in Griffiths book and in section 3.2 he introduces the method of images for a point charge at a distance $d$ from a grounded conducting plane at potential $V = 0$. In subsection 3.2.3, Griffiths compute the energy of the real system and the image charge system and obtain results differing by a factor of 2, The explanation of griffiths is that  in the image problem, we do work on both charges bringing them from infinity to a distance $2d$ apart from each other. However in the real problem, griffiths says that we do work only on the point charge $q$, since the induced charge on the conductor moves along an equipotential. My problem is: if the potential inside the grounded conductor still $V=0$ even with the external electric field due to the point charge,  how charges can be induced, since no force acts on them? I've tried to re-read conductors section in griffiths chapter 2, but as long as I remember, he makes no mention to this problem.

*I've already read some questions related to this topic but none of them answered my question*\

*Also sorry for possible typos, I'm still learning english*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Interesting question. This stumped me for a second, but I think the following argument explains it:

Imagine moving the point charge $q$ a tiny bit closer to the grounded plate (a displacement $dx$, say). Before this displacement, the charges in the plate are in equilibrium and the plate is at $V=0$. After the displacement, then *instantaneously*, the charges in the grounded plate will feel a force (and $V$ will not be uniformly zero), and very quickly rearrange themselves into a new equilibrium position.

However, since the displacement of the charge $q$ was infinitesimal, the charges in the plate will only move an infinitesimal distance $dr$ due an infinitesimal force $dF$ in order to reach their new equilibrium, so that the total work done on the charges in moving from one equilibrium to the other is of the order $(dr)(dF)$, which is a product of differentials so can be ignored, i.e., the work done is zero!

The reason this isn't usually talked about is because conductors are usually treated in *electrostatics*, where moving charges aren't part of the theory. Since there are ways to argue that the field in a conductor is zero, discussions of how the charges got to their equilibrium positions in the first place are usually avoided. But for this example, I think the above explanation works.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Tottaly clarifying answer. Thanks for your time